# Line spacing issues

Tags: line-spacing

I am making a resume. As I am a beginner, I tried to do some line spacing using commands `\vspace` and `\vfill`.
But I do not seem to get expected results. I want the line spacing wherever present to be uniform through out the document. Can anyone suggest me anything, so that I can work on it.

I also tried working with `\onehalfspacing` and `\onespacing` commands, but none seem to give good results.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
%-----------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[top=0.75in, bottom=0.75in, left=0.55in, right=0.85in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{pbox}
\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\star$}
\fontfamily{SansSerif}
\selectfont
\raggedbottom
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage
%[ansinew]
[utf8]
{inputenc}

\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{mygrey}{gray}{0.75}
\textheight=9.75in
\raggedbottom

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}
\newcommand{\isep}{-2 pt}
\newcommand{\lsep}{-0.5cm}
\newcommand{\psep}{-0.6cm}
\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\circ$}

\pagestyle{empty}
%-----------------------------------------------------------
%Custom commands
\newcommand{\resitem}[1]{\item #1 \vspace{-2pt}}
\newcommand{\resheading}[1]{{\small \colorbox{mygrey}{\begin{minipage}{0.975\textwidth}{\textbf{#1 \vphantom{p\^{E}}}}\end{minipage}}}}
\newcommand{\ressubheading}[3]{
\begin{tabular*}{6.62in}{l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} r}
    \textsc{{\textbf{#1}}} & \textsc{\textit{[#2]}} \\
\end{tabular*}\vspace{-8pt}}
%-----------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
\linespread{1.25}
\hspace{0.5cm}\\[-0.2cm]

\textbf{Anupam Bisht} \\
\indent $2^{nd}$ Year, B.Tech Student\\
\indent Electrical and Electronics Engineering
\hfill Ph: +91 7200660151\\
\indent VIT University, Vellore, TN -632014
\hfill Email: anupam.bisht2015@vit.ac.in \\

\resheading{\textbf{OBJECTIVE} }\\[\lsep]
\vspace{4mm} \vfill
\indent To obtain a job in a core-company so that the technical skills and the knowledge acquired during the past \indent can  be used to develop a new solution or optimize existing solutions for the profit of company as well as \indent betterment of the society.

\vspace{2mm}
\resheading{\textbf{ACADEMIC DETAILS} }\\[\lsep]
\vspace{5mm} \vfill
%\begin{table}[ht!]
%\begin{center}
\indent \begin{tabular}{ l @{\hskip 0.15in} l @{\hskip 0.20in} l @{\hskip 0.20in} l @{\hskip 0.20in} l }
\hline
\vspace{0.1mm}
\textbf{Year} &\textbf{Degree} & \textbf{Institute}   & \textbf{CGPA/\%} \\
\hline
2015- Present&B.Tech Electrical and Electronics Engineering & VIT Vellore  & 9.69 CGPA \\

2015 & 12th CBSE Board Examination & Kendriya Vidyalaya & 94.8\%\\

2013 & 10th CBSE Board Examination & Kendriya Vidyalaya & 10 CGPA\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
%\end{center}
%\end{table}
\vspace{2mm}

%\resheading{\textbf{FIELDS OF INTEREST} }\\[\lsep]
%\begin{itemize}
%\item \noindent Wireless Network and Network Security, %Another one, a third one
%\end{itemize}
\resheading{\textbf{AREA OF INTEREST} }\\[\lsep]
\vspace{1.0mm}
\begin{itemize}
\item Medical Sensors, circuit design, computer interfacing of hardware, control systems.
\end{itemize}
\vfill

\resheading{\textbf{TECHNICAL SKILLS} }\\[\lsep]
\vfill \vspace{1.0mm}
\begin{itemize}
\item \noindent \textbf{Languages:\space} C ,\space C++,\space Python, \space R
\item \noindent \textbf{Tools:\space}MATLAB,\space Orcad Pspice,\space Arduino\space, LabView ,\space\LaTeX
\item \noindent \textbf{Platforms:\space} Linux and Windows
\end{itemize}

\resheading{\textbf{PROJECTS} }\\[\lsep]
\vfill \vspace{0.5mm}
\begin{itemize}\itemsep2pt
\item \textbf{Calculation of HeartBeat using Photoplethysmogram in LabVIEW.} \textit{(Feburary 2017 - Currently Working)}
\end{itemize}
\indent We have designed to algorithms, which are inspired from the Pan-Tompkins Algorithm for QRS waveform detection for calculation of heartbeat. We also trying to do statistical analysis of the data using the R software


\resheading{\textbf{EXTRA CURRICULAR ACTIVITIES} }\\[\lsep]
\begin{itemize}
\item \noindent  A volunteer at Kulethi primary school Champawat,Uttarakhand. I helped to promote tablet assisted teaching in the primary school.Also helped in video making of basic science experiments in Hindi, which are uploaded in YouTube.(June 2016)

\item \noindent  Core Committee member at IEEE student chapter of VIT University.
(October 2015 - March 2016)

\end{itemize}

\resheading{\textbf{ACHIEVEMENTS} }\\[\lsep]
\begin{itemize}

\item \noindent  Awarded with cash prize for ranking 3rd out of the 250 students in the branch at VIT University for the academic year 2016-17.

\item \noindent  Awarded with cash prize for ranking 2nd out of the 250 students in the branch at VIT University for the academic year 2015-16.

\item \noindent  Awarded with cash prize for scoring 10 CGPA in class 10th Board Examination.

\item \noindent  Selected to represent KVS for Jawaharlal Nehru National Science, Mathematics and Environment Exhibition for children(JNNSMEE) held at Gangtok, Sikkim during November 2013.

\item \noindent  Awarded 3rd Prize at KVS National Level Science Exhibition held at Kendriya Vidiyalaya Ballygunge, Kolkata for the project titled "Principle of Fiber Optic Communication and Related  Applications" in the year 2012.

\end{itemize}


%\resheading{\textbf{MAJOR PROJECTS AND SEMINAR} }\\[\lsep]
%\begin{itemize}
%\item \textbf{Media Access Control Controling
%} (Research Project) \\
% \emph{(Guide:Prof. Hubert F.
%, May'13 - till date)} \\[-0.6cm]
%   \begin{itemize}\itemsep \isep
%   \item Objective :Performance analysis of HTTP web browsing traffic.
%.
%   \item Performance analysis will help in comparing different MAC protocols based on different network sce-
%narios.

 \end{document}
```

Comment: Were you using the `setspace` package when you tried `\onehalfspacing`? And please consider minimizing the code example you share as much as you can; this will only help us help you more quickly.

Comment: Yes , I was using the package. The whole code has spacing errors. You would understand once you run it.

Comment: You could start by removing all the `\noindent` and `\indent` commands (neither of which shoulf be in a latex document) and most of the `\\ ` commands (certainly `\\ ` should never be used at the end of a paragraph) also most of the `\vfil` and `\vspace` commands are going to produce inconsistent spacing. Once the markup is cleaner it would be easier to suggest changes to get whatever effect that you need.

Answer (score 4):

Before looking at the output it is best to fix all the warnings.

there  are several

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 45--46
```

all due to misuse of `\\` so remove those, apart from use in `tabular`

then there are several

```
Overfull \hbox (8.59479pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 54--55
[][][][][][][]
```

one from each `\resheading` line.

so replace the guessed `0.975\textwidth` by `\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep\relax`

then there is the warning

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/SansSerif/m/n' undefined
```

which is from

```
\fontfamily{SansSerif}\selectfont
```

I assume you intended  `\sffamily`

I then deleted the duplicated `\raggedbottom` and deleted the primitive syntax assignment to `\textheight` as you have already used `geometry` to set the page.

Then I deleted all the `\noindent` and `\indent`

Then the markup is at least reasonable, and there are no warnings from TeX so only then look at the PDF.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
%-----------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[top=0.75in, bottom=0.75in, left=0.55in, right=0.85in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{pbox}
\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\star$}

\sffamily
\raggedbottom
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage
%[ansinew]
[utf8]
{inputenc}

\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{mygrey}{gray}{0.75}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}
\newcommand{\isep}{-2 pt}
\newcommand{\lsep}{-0.5cm}
\newcommand{\psep}{-0.6cm}
\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\circ$}

\pagestyle{empty}
%-----------------------------------------------------------
%Custom commands
\newcommand{\resitem}[1]{\item #1 \vspace{-2pt}}
\newcommand{\resheading}[1]{%
\par
\medskip
{\small
\noindent
\colorbox{mygrey}{\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{\textbf{#1 \vphantom{p\^{E}}}}\end{minipage}}\par
\nopagebreak
\smallskip}}

\newcommand{\ressubheading}[3]{
\begin{tabular*}{6.62in}{l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} r}
    \textsc{{\textbf{#1}}} & \textsc{\textit{[#2]}} \\
\end{tabular*}\vspace{-8pt}}
%-----------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
\linespread{1.25}

\noindent
\textbf{Anupam Bisht} \\
$2^{nd}$ Year, B.Tech Student\\
Electrical and Electronics Engineering
\hfill Ph: +91 7200660151\\
VIT University, Vellore, TN -632014
mail: anupam.bisht2015@vit.ac.in

\resheading{\textbf{OBJECTIVE}}


To obtain a job in a core-company so that the technical skills and the knowledge acquired during the past can  be used to develop a new solution or optimize existing solutions for the profit of company as well as betterment of the society.


\resheading{\textbf{ACADEMIC DETAILS}}

\begin{tabular}{ l @{\hskip 0.15in} l @{\hskip 0.20in} l @{\hskip 0.20in} l @{\hskip 0.20in} l }
\hline
\vspace{0.1mm}
\textbf{Year} &\textbf{Degree} & \textbf{Institute}   & \textbf{CGPA/\%} \\
\hline
2015- Present&B.Tech Electrical and Electronics Engineering & VIT Vellore  & 9.69 CGPA \\

2015 & 12th CBSE Board Examination & Kendriya Vidyalaya & 94.8\%\\

2013 & 10th CBSE Board Examination & Kendriya Vidyalaya & 10 CGPA\\
\hline
\end{tabular}


\resheading{\textbf{AREA OF INTEREST}}


\begin{itemize}
\item Medical Sensors, circuit design, computer interfacing of hardware, control systems.
\end{itemize}


\resheading{\textbf{TECHNICAL SKILLS}}


\begin{itemize}
\item \textbf{Languages:}  C ,\space C++,\space Python, \space R
\item \textbf{Tools:} MATLAB,\space Orcad Pspice,\space Arduino\space, LabView ,\space\LaTeX
\item \textbf{Platforms:}  Linux and Windows
\end{itemize}

\resheading{\textbf{PROJECTS}}

\begin{itemize}\itemsep2pt
\item \textbf{Calculation of HeartBeat using Photoplethysmogram in LabVIEW.} \textit{(Feburary 2017 - Currently Working)}
\end{itemize}

We have designed to algorithms, which are inspired from the Pan-Tompkins Algorithm for QRS waveform detection for calculation of heartbeat. We also trying to do statistical analysis of the data using the R software


\resheading{\textbf{EXTRA CURRICULAR ACTIVITIES}}

\begin{itemize}
\item A volunteer at Kulethi primary school Champawat,Uttarakhand. I helped to promote tablet assisted teaching in the primary school.Also helped in video making of basic science experiments in Hindi, which are uploaded in YouTube.(June 2016)

\item   Core Committee member at IEEE student chapter of VIT University.
(October 2015 - March 2016)

\end{itemize}

\resheading{\textbf{ACHIEVEMENTS}}

\begin{itemize}

\item   Awarded with cash prize for ranking 3rd out of the 250 students in the branch at VIT University for the academic year 2016-17.

\item   Awarded with cash prize for ranking 2nd out of the 250 students in the branch at VIT University for the academic year 2015-16.

\item   Awarded with cash prize for scoring 10 CGPA in class 10th Board Examination.

\item   Selected to represent KVS for Jawaharlal Nehru National Science, Mathematics and Environment Exhibition for children(JNNSMEE) held at Gangtok, Sikkim during November 2013.

\item   Awarded 3rd Prize at KVS National Level Science Exhibition held at Kendriya Vidiyalaya Ballygunge, Kolkata for the project titled "Principle of Fiber Optic Communication and Related  Applications" in the year 2012.

\end{itemize}



 \end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

It may be that that isn't quite the line spacing that you want but it should form a more stable base for any further specification of the spacing.

Comment: You have my greatest respect for answering a question like that. Other *great* question [arise from it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/364894/options-for-line-spacing-other-than-vspace-and-vfill).