# Text goes to new Page even though there is enough space

Tags: page-breaking

I tried changing the bottom and top of the geometry but still the text is showing on new page instead of on the same page. Please Is there a way to fix this?

I am really new to tex. Thanks a lot

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=0.3in, left=0.4in, right=0.5in, bottom=0.2in}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{mygrey}{gray}{0.75}
\textheight=9in
\raggedbottom

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}
\newcommand{\isep}{-1 pt}
\newcommand{\lsep}{-0.3cm}
\newcommand{\psep}{0.6cm}
\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\circ$}

\pagestyle{empty}
%-----------------------------------------------------------
%Custom commands
\newcommand{\resitem}[1]{\item #1 \vspace{-2pt}}
\newcommand{\resheading}[1]{{\small \colorbox{mygrey}{\begin{minipage}{0.975\textwidth}{\textbf{#1 \vphantom{p\^{E}}}}\end{minipage}}}}
\newcommand{\ressubheading}[3]{
\begin{tabular*}{1in}{l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} r}
    \textsc{{\textbf{#1}}} & \textsc{\textit{[#2]}} \\
\end{tabular*}\vspace{-2pt}}
%-----------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \textbf{\Huge Rishabhdeep Singh\\ [0.2cm]}  
    \indent \hfill \break
    \indent D-226, Azad Hall of Residence, \hfill Email-id : \textbf{rishabhdeepsingh98@gmail.com}\\
    \indent Indian Institute of Technology, Kharagpur \hfill Mobile No.: \textbf{+91-8557030007} \\
    \indent West Bengal, INDIA - 721302  \hfill LinkedIn : \href{https://www.linkedin.com/in/rishabhdeepsingh/}{linkedin.com/in/rishabhdeepsingh} \\ 
\end{center}

\hspace{0.3cm} \\[-0.5cm]
\resheading{\textbf{ACADEMIC DETAILS} } \\[0.2cm]
\indent 
\begin{tabular}{ l @{\hskip 0.4in} l @{\hskip 0.5in} l @{\hskip 0.2in} l @{\hskip 0.15in} l }

\hline
\textbf{Education} & \textbf{Institute} & \textbf{Year} & \textbf{CGPA / \%} \\
\hline \break \\[-0.3cm]
    Bachelor of Technology: & Indian Institute of Technology, Kharagpur & 2016 - 2020 & \textbf{6.46 / 10}\\ 
    % {Mechanical Engineering} & &\\ \\[-0.3cm]
    Senior Secondary: & Guru Ram Dass Academy Sr. Sec. School, Aujla & 2016 &\textbf{100 \%}\\ 
    Secondary: & Jiya Lal Mittal D.A.V. Public School, Gurdaspur  & 2014 & \textbf{9.6 / 10}\\
\end{tabular} \\[-0.6cm]

\hspace{0.3cm} \\[0.25cm]
\resheading{\textbf{SKILLS \& EXPERTISE} } \\[-0.4cm]
\begin{itemize}
\item[] \noindent
    \textbf{Programming Languages :} C++, Java, Python, JavaScript, Android, Maven, Bash, HTML, CSS, {\LaTeX{}} \\
    \textbf{Database :} MongoDB \\
    \textbf{Frameworks \& Libraries :} Chromium Embedded Framework, Eectron \\
    \textbf{Software Packages:} Intellij Idea, Android Studio, Visual Studio Code, PyCharm, MS Office \\
    \textbf{CAD \& CAE :} SolidWorks, Autocadm ANSYS \\
\end{itemize}

% \hspace{0.3cm} \\[-0.6cm]
% \resheading{\textbf{RELEVANT COURSES} } \\[-0.6cm]
% \begin{itemize}
% \item[] \noindent High Performance Parallel Programming | Programming and Data Structure | Soft Computing\ | Thermodynamics\ | Economics\ | Fluid Mechanics\ | Kinematics Of Machines | Basic Electronics\ | Engineering Drawing \& Computer Graphics\ | Transform Calculus\ |Partial Differential Equation
% \end{itemize}

\hspace{0.5cm} \\[-0.6cm]
\resheading{\textbf{PROJECTS} }

\begin{itemize}[wide=3pt]
\item \textbf{Google Code-In Mentor | OpenRoberta Lab \hfill December, 2019 - Jan, 2020} \\[-0.6cm]
\begin{itemize} \itemsep \isep
    \item Mentored a total of \textbf{39} Students working on \textbf{13} different Tasks setup by ORG mentors and admins.
    \item Walkthrough the codebase of Open Roberta Lab and assisting students while setting up the lab.
\end{itemize} 

\item \textbf{Software Developer | Intugine Technologies \hfill May, 2019 - July, 2019} \\[-0.6cm]
\begin{itemize} \itemsep \isep
    \item Built an Algorithm for resolving the wrong Jump/Ping points and deploying it on the main website using NodeJS.
    \item Automated Billing and Late Trips Report which are circulated monthly or daily using \textbf{AWS lambdas}
    \item Built a parser for the Database using python and deploy it to the \textbf{Python Package Index(PyPI) Repository}.
    \item Collected data from \textbf{Open Street Map} for different locations of India and used as a training set for ETA Prediction.
    \item Worked on modules for Trips, Battery Percentage, Halts for new Operations dashboard programmed in Python.
\end{itemize} 

\item \textbf{Google Summer of Code | OpenRoberta Lab \hfill May, 2018 - August, 2018} \\[-0.6cm]
    \begin{itemize} \itemsep \isep
        \item Integrate the server and a Web-View using \textbf{Chromium Embedded Framework(CEF)} running it entirely locally.
        \item Customized important features of the Web-UI that were not required in the Standalone version of the software.
        \item Combining the \textbf{Blockly} elements with the Parts of USB program to allow it to work with the local Robots.
        \item Finally bundling the app as an Android app which helps in transferring the code directly to the robot using mobile.
\end{itemize}


\item \textbf{Kharagpur Winter of Code | Student Developer \hfill December, 2018 - January, 2019} \\[-0.5cm]
    \begin{itemize} \itemsep \isep
        \item Participated in Different Android Projects in Kharagpur Winter of Code held by IIT Kharagpur.
        \item Properly structured the code for the TicTacToe App by creating different directories for assets, resources and code.
        \item Added support to Landscape mode and removed Splash screen for Voice Calculator.
    \end{itemize} 
\end{itemize}

\hspace{0.5cm} \\[-0.2cm]
\resheading{\textbf{AWARDS \& ACHIEVEMENTS} }\\[-0.3cm]
\begin{itemize} \itemsep \isep
    \item Secured \textbf{1st rank} among \textbf{3.40 lakhs} students in senior secondary in Punjab School Education Board, 2016-17
    \item Secured \textbf{1st rank} in Codechef Competitive Coding October Challenge 2018 Division 2
    \item \textbf{Bronze} Medal in Weightlifting(Under 77Kg) at Sangram IIT Roorkee, 2018 and Open IIT Powerlifting, 2018.
\end{itemize}

\hspace{0.5cm} \\[-0.2cm]
\resheading{\textbf{CO-CURRICULAR ACTIVITIES} } \\[-0.6cm]
\begin{itemize} \itemsep \isep
    \item Active member of National Sports Organization (NSO), IIT Kharagpur from July 2016 - April 2018
    \item Part of Silver Winning Illumination and Rangoli team of Azad Hall of Residence, IIT Kharagpur
    \item Part of Publicity and Event Managing teams of Khoj 2017, a treasure hunt event organized for first-years
    \item Frequently participate in Competitive Coding contests and open source projects
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Maybe it is linked to using the `book` class? Did you try with `article` or `report`?

Comment: @Bernard Yes with both. Still the same Issue.

Comment: Remove the `\textheight=9in`. And remove all this `\\[-0.6cm]` -- using `\\ ` outside tabular is almost always wrong.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Should I also remove these `\\[-0.2cm]` after `\hspace` ?

Comment: I would remove any one outside a tabular. The \hspace look odd too.

Comment: Thanks a Lot, @UlrikeFischer . It did fix it. Also, I found a similar example as well [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/364852/line-spacing-issues)